# VBA excel average

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to calculate the average of multiples columns into each months of the year through a VBA code without having to divide by the numbers of weeks for each month. Can someone help me to figure out where I have to insert the average in my code?

```
Private Sub CALCULATE_BTN_Click()
    Dim DBS As Database
    Dim RST As Recordset
    Dim SQL_TXT As String
    Range("AA9:BV10").Select
    Selection.Clear

    If OPEN_DBS(DBS, FUEL_DB) Then
        SQL_TXT = "SELECT * FROM FUEL_DATA"
        If OPEN_RST(DBS, RST, SQL_TXT) Then
            While Not RST.EOF
                For i = 1 To 12
                    If Month(RST![FUELDATA_DATE]) = Month(Cells(8, 26 + i).Value) And Year(RST![FUELDATA_DATE]) = Year(Cells(8, 26 + i).Value) Then
                        Cells(9, 26 + i).Value = Cells(9, 26 + i).Value + RST![FUELDATA_AUTOMOTIVE] / 9 / 1000
                    End If
                Next i
                RST.MoveNext
            Wend
            RST.Close
        End If
        DBS.Close
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What data do you want to average? How about you write code to average that data? What is your question?

Comment: The **best** way of doing this would be within the SQL itself.

Comment: here above is the code to calculate the Fuel index for 9 countries by weeks translate into months (January, February and so on) through an Access database. With this code I can estimate the sum by months but not the average. I'm wondering where exactly I have to insert the average functions?